# How can i add extra attribute fields to the asp.net dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, field

Below I am able to set values and the text:

```
dropListUserImages.DataValueField = "Value";
dropListUserImages.DataTextField = "Text";
dropListUserImages.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = srText, Value = srValue});
```

I also want to set extra attributes such as:

```
data-imagesrc
data-description
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
ListItem test  = new ListItem { Text = srText, Value = srValue}
test.Attributes.Add("data-imagesrc", "xxx");
test.Attributes.Add("data-description", "xxx");
dropListUserImages.Items.Add(test);
```

Comment: Just saw this after I posted mine :-)

Comment: @Mounhim you are correct, http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7314  but that is because you can not get access to the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same challenge with translating complex lists of object into values that can be read on the front end, I've used logic similar to the below and found it very useful because it can be adaptive for every type of object:

```
//Object can be whichever type as you wish
List<Object> example = new List<Object>();

var listItemExamples = example
    .Select(a => new Func<ListItem>(() => {
                ListItem item = new ListItem(a.PropropertyA.ToString(), a.PropropertyB.ToString() );
                item.Attributes["data-PropropertyC"] = a.PropropertyC.ToString();
                return item;
            })())
    .ToArray();

dropListUserImages.Items.AddRange(listItemExamples);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, exactly what I needed!