# Display companyname and logo in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I want to display company name and logo in dropdownlist.I have fetch all the company name in dropdownlist but i am not able to add logo with name.

I have xml file where company name and images are specified.
Structure of xml file:

```
 <ente>
    <nazione>ALBANIA</nazione>
    <name>Tirana</name>
    <img>tvsh-albania.png</img>
    <descri>TVSH - Rruga Ismail Quemali 11, Tirana</descri>
    <latitudine>41.321102</latitudine>
    <longitudine>19.823112</longitudine>
    <zoom>-4</zoom>
  </ente>
```

I have all images in image folder also.

I have use this code:

```
 Protected Sub BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist()
        Dim xmlreader As New XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("XMLFILE.xml"))
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader)
        xmlreader.Close()

            If ds.Tables.Count <> 0 Then

                ddlDetails.DataSource = ds

            ddlDetails.DataTextField = "nome"
            ddlDetails.DataValueField = "nome"
            ddlDetails.DataBind()
            End If
    End Sub
```

What i need to do so i can also display image with company name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, which kind of application are you developing? Is it a web application, a Windows Form application or else?

Comment: Thanks Andrea,its a web application.

Answer (score 0):

[Dropdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) list out of the box does not support adding images. Look for 3rd party components.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite hard to achieve in html and .net but it should be easier with a jQuery plugin, for example [this](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) one

Comment: hi Andera,if i have to display 100 items in dropdown then i need to write them manually??

Comment: No, you don't have to write them manually: if you are using webForms (aspx pages) you can add a custom attribute to your DropDownList (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227254/how-can-i-add-extra-attribute-fields-to-the-asp-net-dropdown-list) for an example) in this way you can add images to your DropDownList in your code behind. If you are using ASP.NET MVC you can do a loop in your view to create your markup using image data stored in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery 
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/749/Image-Select-Elements-with-jQuery-and-CSS3.html

**Or try this**
http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

At example 2.. the HTML need to look like this

```
 <select id="demo-htmlselect">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Twitter">Twitter</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Foursquare">Foursquare</option>
    </select>
```

You can create that HTML from Code Behind by binding to a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="rp" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <select id="demo-htmlselect">
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <option value='<%#Container.DataItem("name")%>' data-imagesrc='<%#Container.DataItem("img")%>'
            data-description='<%#Container.DataItem("descri")%>'>
                <%#Container.DataItem("name")%>
        </option>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
    </select>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```